# How to make change text and image size on wordpress search results?

Tags: css, wordpress

I modified existing theme templates and css file and still need some help. I need to change the way the posts are displayed.

Content is currently displayed at 844px width, these are the entries in style.css

```
#content { 
 width: 844px;
 float: left;
}
```

Now I want that posts will now be displayed 3 in columns with 240 width of image size, that will be automaticly taken along with text. The text needs to be smaller to properly fit with the image.

Site url: http://www.virmodrosti.com

How do I do that? If you search for "vitamin d" for example you get all posts in one column without image showed in results. I will really appreciate if you can tell me how to do that, because I would also use the new structure for related articles on each page when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS only you can use:

```css
#content {
    width: 844px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#content .post {
    padding-bottom: 19px;
    max-width: 240px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

#content .p-info {
    border-top: 1px solid #D6D7D6;
    color: #808080;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 13px 22px;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: What about automatic image resize on each post? search results never showed image in any size, it is not included. this sohuld be probabla ydone in functions.php?